# Adding a value to a dropdown using Javascript in a Laravel Blade file

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I have what I think is a simple question.

I have a small javascript script on a laravel blade file that outputs the a list of states into a dropdown control, depending on the selected country from another dropdown control.

The 2 tables are simple, they are a list of countries and a list of states The states table lists states against a country_id.

It all works fine, but what I want, is to add at the top of the presented list of states, a "Not Needed" option at the top of the presented states.

Here is the JS script within the view (blade file)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // SM - State Lookup based on country
  jQuery(document).ready(function ()
  {
          
          jQuery('select[name="service_country_id"]').on('change',function(){
          var countryID = jQuery(this).val();
          if(countryID)
          {
              jQuery.ajax({
                  url : '/getStates/' +countryID,
                  type : "GET",
                  dataType : "json",
                  success:function(data)
                  {
                      console.log(data);
                      jQuery('select[name="service_state_id"]').empty();
                      jQuery.each(data, function(key,value){
                      $('select[name="service_state_id"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                      });
                  }
              });
          }
          else
          {
              $('select[name="state"]').empty();
          }
          });
  });
</script>
```

Here is the dropdowns in the same view (blade file).

```
              <div class="form-group col-sm-11 col-md-5">
                <label class="form-country" for="country">Country <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <select v-model="form.country" class="form-select" id="service_country_id" name="service_country_id">
                    <option value="">Select One...</option>
                        @foreach ($countries as $key => $value)
                            <option value="{{ $value->id }}">{{ $value->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-sm-11 col-md-5">
                  <label class="form-state" for="state">State <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                  <select v-model="form.state" class="form-select" id="service_state_id" name="service_state_id">
                      <option>Select One...</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
```

Here is the search and output from the controller.

```
public function getStates($id) 
{        
    $states = DB::table("states")->where("country_id",$id)->pluck("name","id");
    return json_encode($states);

}
```

I am just trying to find a simple way to concatinate my json_encoded array "Not Needed" to the top of the dropdown control's list of available states.

Answer (score 0):

I maybe misunderstanding, but just write your default state directly into you blade file.

Comment: So in the html select put an option that full fills your default case and append your js

Comment: And if you need it in some cases and not others display none via css

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your input. The above JS overrides and just dumps all values from the controller (from the state database) that match the country ID directly to the state dropdown. I do have a default case in the dropdown but the JS overrides it. I will amend the question to include the dropdowns and the controller.

Comment: If you could show me the select html and controller I can help more

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and decided to just add a "Not Needed" option to the array as per below into the controller and this works. It would still be good to know how to do it in the JS file, but this works for now.

```
$states[0] = "Not Needed";
```